# Neo4j Return Distinct Node With Least Amount of Hops

Tags: asp.net-mvc, graph, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have the following data:

```
A --> B
B --> C
```

Consider this query:

```
START n = node(A, B)
MATCH p = n-[*..2]-(x)
RETURN n.Name, x.Name, length(p)
```

Starting with 2 input nodes, traverse to other nodes with no more than 2 hops.

The following is returned:

```
==> +------------------------------------------------+
==> | n.Name       | x.Name              | length(p) |
==> +------------------------------------------------+
==> | "A"          | "C"                 | 2         |
==> | "B"          | "C"                 | 1         |
```

Backstory: In my app you can search for interests (multiple at a time). Each interest can have related interests. Sometimes the input interests share common interests which results in duplicated interests.

Comment: I'm searching and searching, but I can't find a question here. Please help me - what do you want to achieve? Are you looking for the shortest path between two nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like simply calling `MIN` does what I'm looking for:

```
RETURN x.Name, min(length(p))
```

So it's going to group by x.Name and take the smallest hop column.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-aggregation.html

> Aggregation can be done over all the matching sub graphs, or it can be
>   further divided by introducing key values. These are non-aggregate
>   expressions, that are used to group the values going into the
>   aggregate functions.

Comment: Nice! Feel free to blog about it.